# Restsharp Not Encoding &s

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm using restsharp to make a call out to an api and it is not encoding &s in parameter values (that's all I've tried so far with characters that need to be url encoded). I've used it before and looked at the source to double check that it does url encode both the key and value of parameters. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

```
...

private static readonly RestClient _client = new RestClient();
public Guid Create(Dto myDto)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET)
    {
    Resource = "GetGuid"
  };

  request.AddParameter("name", myDto.Name);
  var response = _client.Execute();

  if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
  {
    Log.Error(string.Format("Could not register user with email {0} in crm", user.Email), this);
    throw new Exception("Response from crm was not OK");
  }

  return Guid.Parse(response.Content);

}

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of I was using was 105.0.0 which seems to have some encoding issues: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/releasenotes.markdown

I haven't looked at the source for that but bumping my version to 105.0.1 seemed to fix the issue.

Commit with the revert that fixed the encoding issue I [encountered](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/commit/8abb790f58d4dd21331d0db4150b6df7a48a7340).